# Initializing structs in Go

Tags: struct, go, initialization, anonymous

Is this valid syntax for initializing a struct in Go?

```
id := struct { name, ltype, value }
```

The fields are all strings. The actual error message I get is "syntax error: unexpected }". Maybe you cant initialize anonymous structs this way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No type inference for you!

```
name := "a"
ltype := "b"
value := "c"
id := struct { name, ltype, value string } { name, ltype, value }
```

Comment: Context: Seinfeld. :)

Comment: And there was I thinking I could save some typing - may as well go back to using `new()` and init all fields by hand!

Comment: You don't need to name the fields in the data part, and you only need one `string` definition which can make it shorter if you want `id := struct {name, ltype, value string}{name, ltype, value}`

Comment: Its a shame - that struct is embedded inside another struct in my code, so initializing this way is tedious. Are the inference rules documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can also initialize the value inline.

`id := struct{ name, ltype, value string }{"a", "b", "c"}`